# Laravel 5 Merge LengthAwarePaginator

Tags: laravel-5, merge

I have 2 objects LengthAwarePaginator from 2 different queries that I'd like to merge to display on the same page/table.

As soon as I merge the 2 objects, I'm losing most of the properties such as the total of elements and can't use the Laravel 5 render() function:

$final = $res_query_1->merge($res_query_2)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function merge(LengthAwarePaginator $collection1, LengthAwarePaginator $collection2)
    {
        $total = $collection1->total() + $collection2->total();

        $perPage = $collection1->perPage() + $collection2->perPage();

        $items = array_merge($collection1->items(), $collection2->items());

        usort($items, array($this, 'cmp'));

        $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($items, $total, $perPage);

        return $paginator;
    }
```

Comment: if there is same element in two collection your `$total` will be incorrect or data has duplicates. Also i'm sure there some bug with `$perPage` to it